# In R testthat gives error when testing function including reticulate::source_python

Tags: r, testthat, reticulate

I want to test a function with `testthat` that includes sourcing a python file with `reticulate`. However, I get the error: **Exited with status 9**.

This is the python example file called **the_py_module.py** with function that I want to source.

```
def f1():
  return "f one"
```

This is the **function sourcing** the above file in R:

```
#' Testing F1 function sourced from python
#' @return "f one"
#' @export
f1_sourced_from_python <- function() {
  reticulate::source_python(system.file("python", "the_py_module.py", package = "test_package", mustWork = TRUE))
  f1()
}
```

This is the **testthat set-up**, which gives above error:

````
test_that("Testing sourcing python file in testthat", {
  output <- f1_sourced_from_python()
  expect_that(output, is_a("character"))
})
```
Any help is much appreciated.
````

Comment: this works as expected on my computer (R 4.0.2).

Comment: No error here (Ubuntu, R 4.0.2). If you want help we need to be able to reproduce the error...

Comment: Thank you for testing this! 
It gives error for me when using Mac OS Catalina version 10.15.6; but it works for me when trying on Windows...